# Adding Hashes Dynamically to an Empty Array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to use Nokogiri to count the occurrences of different class attributes that appear on a website. To do this I am implementing a breadth-first search and every time I encounter a new class attribute I want to store it in a hash with a unique ID. And every that same class attribute is encountered I want to find that same hash and increment its occurrence key.

I am attempting to store all these hashes in an array:

```
hashArray = []

new hash = {
  id: uniqueID,
  occurrence: 1,
  className: node["class"]
}
```

Ideally, I would have something like this at some point:

```
  array = [
  {id: 1, occurrences: 3, className: 'wrapper'},
  {id: 2, occurrences: 5, className: 'media'}
  ]
```

How can I initialize a new hash to add to the array everytime my search encounters a new class?

I tried this:

```
hashArray << {id: uniqueID, occurrence: 1, className: node["class"]}
```

but this method leads to the array only holding one hash at a time.

Comment: Instead of an array of hashes, have you considered constructing a hash `h` whose keys are  the (unique) id's and whose values are hashes such as `{ occurrence: 1, className: node["class"] }`? That way, for each new `id` (say`3`), you could execute `h.key?(3)`. If `false`, add a new key/value pair, `h[3] = { occurrences: 3, className: ??? }`. if `true`, `update: h[3][:occurrence] += 1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland And then mangle it into an array-of-hashes at the end if that's the structure that's really needed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah yes I see. This is a good implementation thank you.

Comment: Also, are you implementing your own BFS? Because you don't have to - let Nokogiri worry about searching. `doc.css('[class]'.each do |element_with_class| ... end`. Also, you'll have much better luck with classes themselves being IDs for the hash - that way you can very quickly find if you have it already or not.

Comment: If you have declaring an empty array you can use `push` operation to add new hash to it.
`hashArray.push(new_hash)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland How can you update the hash conditionally? Like say: h.map{|key| if key[:occurrence] > 2 then key[:occurrence] += 1 end}. I know this syntax doesn't work.

Comment: `h.map { |key|  ...` will only allow you to modify the values of existing keys. When you identify an attribute `att` from a website it may or may not be a key of `h`. That's when you execute `if h.key?(att) h[att] += 1 else h[k] = {occurrences: 1, className: ??? }; end`. Note that in my comment above I wrote `h[k] = {occurrences: 3, className: ??? }`. That (which I copied and pasted) was in error in that `occurrences` should be initialized to `1` for new keys.

Answer (score 0):

I see that both ids and classNames are unique, if you use `classNames` as identifier, you might not need to add an additional `id`. Here is an approach that should work like you described:

```
# Initialise a Hash which values default to 0 (instead of nil)
occurrences = Hash.new(0)

# Example:
# occurrences['foo'] # => 0
# occurrences        # => {}


# For all relevant nodes, count occurrences of their class names
occurrences[node["class"]] += 1

# Example:
# occurrences['bar'] += 1 # => 1
# occurrences['bar'] += 1 # => 2
# occurrences['foo'] += 1 # => 1
# occurrences             # => {"bar"=>2, "foo"=>1}


# Add ids and format array, where ids are the index of the element
occurrences.map.with_index do |list, id|
  {id: id, occurence: list.last, className: list.first}
end

# Example:
# => [{:id=>0, :occurence=>2, :className=>"bar"}, {:id=>1, :occurence=>1, :className=>"foo"}]
```

I hope you find that helpful.